Package http-proxy-middleware with create-react-app not working
So I'm creating an app with create-react-app and I'm trying to use a proxy to solve all the CORS stuff.
I've tried everything but there's no way to make it work but I'm 100% sure that I'm missing something stupid.
This is my files structure:

setupProxy.js content:
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'https://i.instagram.com',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};

This is how I make the call:
  const username = 'holaquetal';
  fetch(`/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=${username}`, {
    headers: {
      'User-Agent':
        'blablabla',
    },
  })

I've read a lot of posts about it here but nothing seems to work, any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance!
